# Getting stale element with selenium testing in C3

Tags: c#, selenium

I am working with Selenium testing I have all the div's that contain an id with a certain name (in this case "center-").

```
var x = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'center-')]"));
```

When I try to foreach or for loop through it for a clickable event:

```
var hitit = item.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
hitit.Click();
```

I get a Stale Element. How could I go about avoiding the Stale element error?
Here is the complete example of the code.

```
   var x = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'center-')]"));
   foreach (var item in x)
        {                 
            var hitit = item.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
            hitit.Click();
            driver.Navigate().Back();                
        }
```

It runs through the first loop fine but when it goes back and tries to run it again is when the error occurs.

Comment: Looking at the selenium [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)  
the most likely cause is the element has been deleted or removed from the DOM.

Can you post a more complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this, you click the link with the line:

```
hitit.Click();
```

That clicks the link and redirects the browser to a new page, you then go back to the old page with:

```
 driver.Navigate().Back();
```

and try to click the next link in the loop. The problem is that the list of elements is not the same elements as what are now displayed on the page, that's why it is stale. To put it another way, the elements have the same class names, but are not the *same* elements.

You need to call FindElements on every time you go back to the original page.
Something like this should work:

```
var x = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'center-')]"));
var elementCount = x.Count();
var loopCounter = 0;
while (loppCounter < elementCount)
{           
        var allCenterDivs = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'center-')]"));      
        var hitit = allCenterDivs[loopCounter].FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
        hitit.Click();
        driver.Navigate().Back();          
        loopCounter++;      
}
```

Comment: Dale - Awesome. Thank you so much. I did have to change the hitit.Click() to hitit.SendKeys(Keys.Enter) because the page wasn't loading fast enough and I was getting an error that the a tag wasn't clickable. But your answer saved my sanity so I appreciate it very much.